# Share data among rules using a Map

Tags: scope, drools, fact

This should be simple, but I am still lost.
There is a very similar post here: [How to share data between Drools rules in a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353997/how-to-share-data-between-drools-rules-in-a-map)
but it doesn't fix my problem:

I have a set of rules and, before launching them, I insert a Map<String, Object> as a fact.
In these rules I use the map to write some conclusions like:

```
when
   $map : Map();
   something ocurrs;
then
   $map.put("conclusion1", 100);
```

Now I would like to use these intermediate conclusions in other rules, something like:

```
when
   $map : Map(this["conclusion1"] > 50)
then
   do something cool;
```

The problem is that when I execute the rules it is like the second rule doesn't see the conclusions of the first one, and it does not fire.
I have tried putting a break point and analysing the working memory, and, in fact, the Map would contain the conclusion1, 100 after the first rule is fired.
I have also tried by making an update($map) in the conclusion, but that would trigger an infinite loop.

Any idea of why this wouldn't work, or any alternative solution to my problem?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify a fact you need to notify the engine you are doing so. One of the ways of doing that is by using modify(). E.g.:

```
when
   $map : Map();
   something ocurrs;
then
   modify( $map ) { 
      put("conclusion1", 100)
   }
end
```

Comment: And to address the infinite loop issue, update the rule that puts the "conclusion1" element on the map to only do so when "conclusion1" doesn't already exist; i.e., `Map( containsKey("conclusion1") == false )`. This will prevent the rule from reactivating when "conclusion1" is part of the keyset.